# View not sending the data array to the AngularJs controller

Tags: angularjs

view

```
<div ng-repeat="supplie in supplies">
<div class="i-checks" >
    <input id="boxInsumo{{supplie.id_supplies}}" type="checkbox" name="name" ng-model="dataSupplies.name" class="form-control-custom col-lg-2" ng-true-value="{{supplie.name}}">
    <label for="boxInsumo{{supplie.id_supplies}}">{{supplie.name}}</label>
        <div class="form-group" >      
            <label>Cantidad</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="cuantity" name="cuantity" ng-model="dataSupplies.cuantity" class="form-control form-control-sm col-lg-5">
        </div>
    </div>                              
</div>

<div><button ng-click="formSupplies(dataSupplies)">SEND</button></div>
```

/***********************************************

controller angulajs

```
$scope.formSupplies = function (dataSupplies) {
        console.log(dataSupplies);
    }
```

Result 
Undefined

Comment: The main Stack Overflow site is English language only, were you looking for [es.so] or [pt.so]?

Comment: I guess the question is "Why data is not sent to my controller"

Answer (score 0):

If supplies is not part of $scope will not work for the ng-repeat, and it will not work as a method parameter.

Also your ng-repeat is not binded to some variables. Instead of:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="cuantity" name="cuantity" ng-model="supplie.cuantity" class="form-control form-control-sm col-lg-5">
```

You may be using:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="cuantity" name="cuantity" ng-model="dataSupplie.cuantity" class="form-control form-control-sm col-lg-5">
```

It appears you're using supplie where you should be using dataSupplie (or viceversa). When you solve that issue, you can use a $filter for the selected items:

```
  $scope.isSelected = function(product) {
    return product.selected;
  };

  $scope.formSupplies = function() {
    var filteredSupplies = 
        $filter('filter')($scope.dataSupplies, $scope.isSelected);
  };
```

Example: https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/KvjqON

Comment: thanks for your answer man, I need send the data that enter in the input checkbox and input number to the controller, but receive "undefined", some example of doing this without using tables

Comment: Okie, I propose you to have also a "selected" flag in your model and don't use parameters at all. Something like this: https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/KvjqON. Then, in the method call you can process the elements that have changed the cuantity values and selected=true

Comment: yes man is correct, but could send alone the checkbox and input selected, and not send all array or in the controller extract alone name, cuantity and push in other array, thanks man.

Comment: I have updated the example link. This is the way I recommend. Think about it: "I want the results filtered" --> you can use a filter

Comment: Good to know. Now consider to accept the answer. Otherwise specify what else you need, so others can help you.